# Import MySQL DAtabase from Data Files

Tags: mysql

I've got the MySQL data files from an old server which has now crashed so I can not login to the server to do mysqldump etc. I am now trying to load the data on a new server. The only option I have is to copy/paste the data files that I have. But when I do so, some of the database tables throw this error "Table does not exist" when I can see it in my Navicat Window. The problem is only with some of the tables, not all.

My question is, how can I fix this error ? Or is there another way to import the data from data files?

Comment: Can you make an example with a specific datbase, and show which data files you have for it?

Comment: There are lots of tables in the DB. For each table, there is a .FRM, .MYD and a .MYI file. Does that help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best piece of advice that comes to my mind is running a [`myisamchk`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html) on the respective table(s), paying special attention to the [repair options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk-repair-options.html).

Be sure to make backups of the data files beforehand.

Additional thoughts:

- Make sure you have restarted the database server after adding the data files.
- Are you sure you are addressing the correct table(s)? Note that on most Linux filesystems, the table name is case sensitive (as it's reflected by a file in the filesystem). So `tablename` != `Tablename`

Comment: hmm tried a few different options. nothing seems to fix the issue. Do you know exactly what repair option I should try ?

Comment: Ah - the table that is throwing the error only has a.FRM for it. No, .MYI or .MYD - what are my options?

Comment: @Jimmy according to [this](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_File_Formats), the .frm file contains the table's description only, no data. I don't know whether there is any tool to at least rebuild the table's structure from a FRM file

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I will have to dig into the archives again to find the .MYD files.